# how to capture cybersource echeck programtically

Tags: magento2, payment

i have credit limits payment method.

first user can place an orders with credit limit payment method.
later i'm trying to create an interface in my account section to pay  all invoice dues at once.

can u give me some solution to capture through cybersource echeck progrmatically.

update:

1. I placed an order with cybersource echeck. Now it is authorized successfully.
   (module default payment action is authorize )
2. I'm trying to create an invoice. Invoice created successfully. But it is not contacting to cybersource gateway to capture the authorized amount.

3.Now i changed vendor/module-echeck/etc/config.xml file :

`<can_capture>0</can_capture>` to  `<can_capture>1</can_capture>`
4. Again I placed an order with cybersource echeck & authorized successfully.

5. Now i'm trying to create invoice, this time it is trying to contact cybersource gateway but its throwing below error.

> report.CRITICAL: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in
>   vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 555
>   {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Illegal offset
>   type in isset or empty in
>   vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 555
>   at vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Comment: Have you configure Payment Action for Secure Acceptance ?

Comment: Set to Authorize Only to reserve funds during checkout and
capture during invoice creation. Set to Authorize

Comment: i have 2 payment methods in checkout ( 1.cybersource echeck with auth,2. credit limit payment(offline))

Comment: Yes, But have you configure the cybersource echeck with auth payment method ?

Comment: yes. Magento2 cyber source echeck module has default payment action is authorize.

Comment: Have you configure Reject Event type ?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87785/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-sivakumar).